# return type deduction with nullptr on one branch

Tags: c++11

Is there a way to force C++17 to convert a nullptr return value safely so that the return type is deduced as a pointer of type T assuming that all branches return either T* or nullptr?

Comment: Would using static_cast<T*>(nullptr) be safe?

Comment: It seems to work but I don't really understand how nullptr types interact with standard pointer types of T*.

Comment: "**[conv.ptr]/1** A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal (2.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of that type..." `nullptr` is the sole value of type `std::nullptr_t`. `static_cast<T*>(nullptr)` produces a null pointer value of type `T*`